# How to stop NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED becoming true when device boots?

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-5.0-lollipop

My application starts when the device boots (Nexus 7). When my device boots `if(action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))` becomes true. Then the code inside the `if` crashes because the intent was not really a `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` but a boot.

I can put a `try catch` and then it won't crash. However then NFC won't work. To get NFC to work the application must be closed and reopened.

Is there a way to check the `if(action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))` but have it ignore the booting? It is really annoying because the if is checking for NFC not boot.

```
@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    // NFC code.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    PendingIntent pi = this.createPendingResult(0x00A, new Intent(), 0);
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pi, null, null);

    try
    {
        // NFC transfer. Receiving message here.
        if(action != null && action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))
        {
            Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage inNdefMessage = (NdefMessage) parcelables[0];
            NdefRecord[] inNdefRecords = inNdefMessage.getRecords();
            NdefRecord NdefRecord_0 = inNdefRecords[0];
            String inMsg = new String(NdefRecord_0.getPayload());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toasty: "+inMsg + action.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            textInfo.setText(inMsg);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("NFC", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

This is the code that checks for BOOTING.

```
public class BootManager extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Login_Activity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

---

In the `Login_Activity`, **Could this be altering the `intent`?**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: How did you register your app to start on boot? Did you register a broadcast receiver for action BOOT_COMPLETED that then starts the activity?

Comment: @MichaelRoland yes I did.

Comment: Then please show that code too.

Comment: @MichaelRoland I have posted it. Let me know if you have any ideas, your previous answer in the related question helped a ton.

Comment: Is the above `onResume()` code from `Login_Activity`? Do you modify the start intent in `onCreate` or `onStart` (e.g. by using `setIntent()`)?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Yes `onResume()` is from `Login_Activity`. I do not modify the start intent in the `onCreate` nor in the `onStart`.

Comment: In that case the intent should not contain an action and `(action != null && action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED))` is supposed to evaluate to `false`.

Comment: @MichaelRoland It's not evaluating to `false`. Could this (check edit above for `NewIntent()`) it might be altering the intent.

Comment: Would be interesting to trace the activity lifecycle. `onNewIntent` should not be invoked upon boot so it should not influence your case. Is there a tag attached while booting?